# How to change the default behaviour for customErrors pages in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, http-status-code-404

I use Asp.Net 4 and C#.

I would like to know how to change the default beahviour of Asp.Net `customErrors`.

In my `Web.Config` file I use this settings.

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

As you can expect if a page is not found a redirect occur to the custom page specified in Web.Config.

---

Requested page:

```
http://localhost:1372/nopagehere
```

---

Result page:

```
http://localhost:1372/ErrorPages/404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/nopagehere
```

---

When I analyse the Http Header for the Result page I can see:

- a 404 Status when the page is not found
- a 302 Status for the new created url

I would like change this behavior in this way:

- when a request to a not found page has been made http://localhost:1372/nopagehere
- the result should be only http://localhost:1372/nopagehere (no 302 redirect) and with status code only on 404.

Any idea how to do it? Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `redirectMode` attribute on your `<customErrors>` section.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

I think you want to set it to `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"`. This throws a 404 and shows the content of your 404 page, but without redirecting to the actual 404 page.

Comment: I would like to remove the redirection and only send 404 status for page not found

Comment: Thanks Jan is working as expected I did not know about this attribute.

Comment: I have a very strange problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269103/problem-with-defaultredirect-in-web-config-customerrors have a look if you have time, I appreciate thanks

Comment: The attribute is new to v4.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure redirectMode has been there since 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe removing the status code 404 from the custom errors and let the default redirect page handle it.